# Touch method UIImageView inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am wondering how I can use a touch method for a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` in xCode.
When I add the `UIImageView` subview to the self.view, I can use the touch method. But when I add the UIImageView subview to the UIScrollView, I can't. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touches = [event allTouches];
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        NSLog(@"Image Touched");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.9)];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
    scrollView.bounces = TRUE;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

     UIImageView *ImageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.04, 10, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.28, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.22)];
     ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed(@"image.png")];
     ImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
     ImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
     ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [scrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}
```

Comment: You should use UITapGestureRecognizer instead..

Comment: When I use that, the whole UIScrollView area is touchable. I want only the UIImageView inside the UIScrollView to be touchable.

Comment: in that case you should add the gesture to UIImageView instead of UIscrollView

Comment: But then the UIScrollView doesn't allow the touch ability of the UIImageView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `UIGestureRecognizers` a try. They are far easier to manage with multiple layers of touch management.

```
- (void)touchedImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // When the gesture has ended, perform your action.
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Touched Image");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.9)];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
    scrollView.bounces = TRUE;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.04, 10, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.28, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.22)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    // Create a tap gesture
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchedImage:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, happy coding :)

Comment: Ryan Poolos  your touch  method is working  perfectly , but will you please let me know , how we can get the current  image from scrollview if we are using multiple image array

Comment: Open a new question and link it here. I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: @RyanPoolos here is my question in swift  http://stackoverflow.com/q/36319713/3400991 for multiple imageview inside scrollview not recognize tapgesture .

Answer (score 2):

if you're dealing with multiple imageviews using the same gesture recognizer, it won't work. Try using a new gesture recognizer per image view.

Comment: Wasted one full day on this issue. Only the last added view was responding to touch events.

Comment: Same here. I had the `UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(touchedImage:)];` part out of the loop, and it didn't work. It has to go into the for loop for multiple image views.

Answer (score 1):

User interaction of UIImageView is disabled by default you can enable it by setting `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to derive a CustomScrollView from UIScrollView and override all touches method like touchesBegan,Moved,Ended and Cancelled like below:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:view];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, pt))
        {
            [view touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
        }

    }
}
```

After you do this. When you add any view in the instance of customScrollView, you'll get the touches in the added view properly.

Comment: User interaction of UIImageView is disabled by default you can enable it by setting imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; or simple you can derive from UIImageView and override its touches.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an image view as a subview in a scroll view when applying a transformation.
Upon scroll my gesture recognizer no longer worked so I checked the offset of the scroll view and reset my image so the gesture was recognized. 
And of course we need to set userInterActionEnabled to true and add the gesture in viewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true 
     addGesture() 

 }

 func addGesture(){
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.enableGesture(_:)));
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
    self.imageView.tag = 1

}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offset > 0 {
        imageView.layer.transform = avatarTransform
    }
    else {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }
}
```