# Tap gesture on multiple imageview inside scrollview not firing event , only first imageview tap gesture working?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Scenario is I have imageview which I have added inside a scrollview and then tapgesture added on each imageview but only first one imageview firing event .

Have tried following :

**1. Created Extension of imageview**

```
extension UIImageView {
  public func openMenu() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("handleTapGesture:"))
    //mImg.addGestureRecognizer()
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    print("open")
  }
}
```

**2. Added tap gesture in the loop (the way imageview are added on scrollview same way tapgesture added )**

```
//the loop go till all images will load
for var index = 0; index < imagesName.count; index++ {
  let mImg: UIImageView = UIImageView()          
  let pDict = homePageProductArr[index] as NSDictionary

  //Create a UIVIEW 
  let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 100))
  let nameLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: xOffset+20, y: 85, width: 100, height: 20))
  nameLabel.text = (pDict.objectForKey("CategoryName") as! String)
  nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 10.0)
  containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)

  let tapMenuCategoryImageTGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTapGesture:"))
  containerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapMenuCategoryImageTGR)

  // make the imageview object because in scrollview we need image
  mImg.frame = CGRectMake(5 + xOffset, 0, 80, 80)
  // the offset represent the values, used so that topleft for each image will
  // change with(5+xOffset, 0)and the bottomright(160, 110)
  //mImg.image = UIImage(named: imagesName[index])
  mImg.imageFromUrl(imagesName[index])
  //mImg.imageFromServerURL(imagesName[index])
  //Creating Circular Image
  //mImg.layer.borderWidth = 1
  mImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
  mImg.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
  mImg.layer.cornerRadius = mImg.frame.height/2
  mImg.clipsToBounds = false
  mImg.openMenu()
  mImg.userInteractionEnabled = true
  mImg.addGestureRecognizer = tapMenuCategoryImageTGR

  // The image will put on the img object
  images.insert(mImg, atIndex: index)
  //Put the img object at the images array which is mutable array
  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(120 + xOffset, 110)
  //scroll view size show after 125 width the scroll view enabled 
  scrollview.addSubview(images[index] as! UIView)
  //set images on scroll view
  xOffset += 100
}
```

Kindly share your suggestions on it .

Comment: Did you try to init tapMenuCategoryImageTGR before your for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by adding button on imageview , and making it background color clear and title to "":

Here is Code Snippet :

```
 //print(mDict.objectForKey("ImageURL"))
    //var scrollWidth: Int = 120
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(120.0, 80.0)
    var xOffset: CGFloat = 5
    //the loop go till all images will load
    for index in 0 ..< imagesName.count {

        let mImg: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        //set placeholder image
        mImg.image = UIImage(named: "lazyload_icon.png")
        let pDict = homePageProductArr[index] as NSDictionary

        //Create a UIVIEW 
        let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 120))
        let nameLabel:UILabel    = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: xOffset+20, y: 95, width: 100, height: 20))
        nameLabel.text = (pDict.objectForKey("CategoryName") as! String)
        nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: Constant().HomeLabelFontSize)
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(Constant().HomeLabelHexColorCode)
        //set line and wrap text
        nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        nameLabel.sizeToFit()
        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        containerView.userInteractionEnabled = false

        // make the imageview object because in scrollview we need image
        mImg.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset , 0, 90, 90)
        // the offset represent the values, used so that topleft for each image will
        // change with(5+xOffset, 0)and the bottomright(160, 110)
        //mImg.image = UIImage(named: imagesName[index])
        mImg.imageFromUrl(imagesName[index])
        //mImg.imageFromServerURL(imagesName[index])
        //Creating Circular Image
        mImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
        mImg.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        mImg.layer.cornerRadius = mImg.frame.height/2
        mImg.clipsToBounds = false
        mImg.userInteractionEnabled = false


        // The image will put on the img object
        images.insert(mImg, atIndex: index)
        // Put the img object at the images array which is mutable array
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(120 + xOffset, 110)
        //scroll view size show after 125 width the scroll view enabled
        containerView.addSubview(images[index] as! UIView)
        scrollview.addSubview(containerView)//images[index] as! UIView)
        // set images on scroll view
        xOffset += 100

        //Adding button to fire event
        let touchButton:UIButton = UIButton()
        touchButton.frame = mImg.frame
        touchButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        touchButton.tag = index
        touchButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("touchCategoryAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        touchButton.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        scrollview.addSubview(touchButton)
        scrollview.bringSubviewToFront(touchButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of UIScrollView. We can use the Gesture to a single view.
Another solution of your problem is given below-

1. You have to declare the tap gesture globally.

   ```
   var  singleTap:UITapGestureRecognizer!
   ```
2. In this step we create a function which takes a the UIimageView and add the gesture on the top of it.

   ```
     func setGesture(img_View:UIImageView)  {
         singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: Selector("resignResponder"))
         singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
       view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
   ```

   }
3. Now create the action of the gesture.

   ```
   func resignResponder()  {

   }
   ```

> These are the three steps as the solution of your problem . Call
>   "setGesture" for every imageView. You can successfully recognize the
>   tap for every imageView.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of using UIImageView you can use UIButton and set the
>   background image to the button and set the title "". Then you don't
>   need to add both UIImageView and UIButton. UIButton can easily got the
>   Tapped event over UIScrollView.

Comment: Single problem have multiple solution . We have to choose the best1. @ShobhakarTiwari

Comment: you should understand full question , its not about single imageview tap , its already done in the question itself, rather it was multiple imageview scrolling horizontally , so thats other issue .

Comment: Yeah you are right , it was multiple imageview scrolling horizontally. you can easily set the tags of multiple button . and check them where you got the tap.